# How to make a unique clone of a variable containing some clonded vlaues and unique value per variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, clone

```
let car = {
    brand: 'Ford',
    model: '556',
    licensePlate: 55554,
}
console.log(car);

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    let car1 = Object.assign({}, car);
    car1.licensePlate += i
    console.log(car1);
};
```

This creates a unique licensePlate, but how can I also have it create car1, car2, car3, car4, car5?

```
car1 = {
            brand: 'Ford',
            model: '556',
            licensePlate: 55554,
        }
car2 = {
            brand: 'Ford',
            model: '556',
            licensePlate: 55555,
        }
car3 = {
            brand: 'Ford',
            model: '556',
            licensePlate: 55556,
        }
```

etc...
I am trying not to use it, as it's redundant
 `let car1 = [...car, LicencePlate: +1]; let car2=  [...car, LicencePlate: +2];`

still new at JavaScript,any help appreciated. In short can one make a for loop for creating unique variables and how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need car1, car2, etc keys, you should use the object, otherwise array...

```
let base = {
  brand: 'Ford',
  model: '556',
  licensePlate: 55554,
}

let carsObj = {};
let carsArr = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    carsObj[`car${i}`] = {
        brand: base.brand,
        model: base.model,
        licensePlate: base.licensePlate + i
    }
    carsArr.push({
        brand: base.brand,
        model: base.model,
        licensePlate: base.licensePlate + i
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks for helping.